# Check if PHP UDP fread is getting a reply/set a timeout

Tags: php, udp

I am creating a website that connects to a windows program on the local network using UDP.

The problem I'm having is that when there is no reply to `fread` the code has a fatal error when the execution time reaches thirty seconds.

As UDP doesn't check if it has a connection there seems to be no way to tell what's going on or to catch the thirty seconds fatal error.

Here is my current code.

```
$fp = fsockopen("udp://1.10.100.28", 24, $errno, $errstr,3);

    if (!$fp) {
        echo "ERROR: $errno - $errstr<br />\n";
    } else {
     $value = $_POST["sendvalue"];
     $out = "setwarpterm 1 1 x ".$value."\r";

     $write = fwrite($fp, $out);

     if($_POST["read"] == "yes"){
         echo fread($fp, 3000);
     }

        fclose($fp);
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: The script already works when it can connect to the program. It simply sends a small string to the program and gets a processed string back.

Comment: The problem is when the connection fails.

Comment: There's no "connection" with UDP. `fread` returns an empty string if it can't get any data after the timeout. You can check for that if you want to handle that case.

Comment: With `echo "hello". fread($fp, 3000);` it doesn't echo anything if the server is not responding. Also none of the echos in the rest of the script output until the fatal error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout didn't work as it wasn't directly above my fread.

```
stream_set_timeout($fp, 2);
echo fread($fp, 3500);
```

This did work and makes the fread return an empty string.